# SSL cert preventing communications between front and back end?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

We're trying to deploy an SSL for our website back end. The back end is written in Java and based on Springboot/Tomcat, while the front end is in React. We have a front end and a back end server, both using EC2.

The front end server has an SSL from Godaddy - 'example_front.com', which is working fine. Where we're having problems is in deploying the (separate) certificate for the back end - 'example_back.com'. A DNS has already been assigned using AWS Route 53 to connect to the back end server IP.

We've used the Godaddy certification files, and configured them in Java (application.properties)    using two files -  Private_key_file.key and Public_key_file.pem.

Currently the website itself works fine, but all functions requiring it to make a request to the back end always fail. The back end works ok when we test it using Postman (when we make a request to the API, we get the correct responses), but it doesn't respond to requests coming from the front end itself.

We've tried a bunch of different things, including switching the front and back end SSL certs, all to no avail. Any suggestions you could make would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: "but it doesn't respond to requests" - What error do you get? What does it say in the browser devtools or wireshark?

Comment: @Robert thanks. The error is "net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH". Have tried the usual Google search.